# How to split a polygon into UNEQUAL parts in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-pro, editing, splitting

Is there a way to simultaneously divide several polygons into UNEQUAL parts in ArcGIS Pro? I have a feature class with multiple rectangles that are all the same size and orientation. Here are three, but there will be more:
[image]
They all need to be divided the same way: three vertical strips, with the center strip being several meters skinnier than the outer two:
[image]
I have only found tools that could divide into equal areas. The other option seems to be painstaking line drawing to use in Edit > Split where I would have to know the X,Y coordinates of each line vertex instead of inputting "86 m in from the east and west edges" into a distance box or something. If Python/ArcPy is my only option, that's fine but I'm not very familiar with them yet.

Comment: No, this isn't a Calculate Geometry task.  There are an *infinite* number of ways to split *each* geometry unequally, so you really ought to [Edit] the Question to include an image/sketch of what you mean. Also, please ask only One question per Question.

Comment: I agree with @Vince, we need to see your data, for example are your rectangles all randomly rotated or all aligned on the horizontal, If they are on the horizontal then you could extract the extent which would be the rectangle itself but then you could query the height/width properties.

Comment: so basically you know how many meters away from corner vertex the first polygon should end? if so, you may segment at this length, etc

Comment: There's no reason to split anything. Your task is to identify the coordinates of the four corners of the geometry (which, for a rectangle orthogonal to the axis is just ulX,ulY,rlX,lrY), determine the X values where the new corners will go (m1X & m2x)  and the assemble three new geometries with X values ulX->m1X, m1X->m2X, and m2X->lrX. It's tedious, but not difficult. Difficulty increases if the rectangles are non-orthogonal, but only because you need to track upper and lower mid-X values (and their corresponding Y values).

Comment: Is there a particular tool to use to collect this information from all the rectangles in the feature class simultaneously? I figured what you're describing is an option, but I'm looking for how to do it en masse. As I said in my question, I'm willing to use Python if that's what it takes but I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me which ArcPy functions are relevant.

Comment: So they are always 252m on the horizontal, what are their height? If you know the height then as @Vince says its an easy geometry problem of building polygons by off set the coordinates by 86m and Xm height.

Comment: Their height is always 140m. I figured that calculating the geometry like that would be one option. So what is the name of the tool, whether it be through editing or analysis, to accomplish this? I apologize if this is a very basic question. My GIS experience so far has mostly included analysis of feature classes created by others. This is my first time creating a large feature class starting from X,Y coordinates rather than from another feature class that wasn't just tracing satellite imagery of buildings as homework.

Comment: There is no tool that does this highly specialized task until you write it, in Python, using ArcPy. I suggest you model this on the MultiPartToSinglePart utility, accepting a source feature class and a target feature class, then creating a new target from the source template, adding a "part" field to the empty target, then using DA InsertCursor with a nested DA SearchCursor to copy all the fields *except* OID and shape, doing the math to split the shape into three parts, and writing three `icursor.insertRow` (different parts) inside the search `for`. This is 30-40 lines of code.